# Angular Vendor.js file size - How to reduce file size

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm fairly new to Angular. I've read that a good file size for the vendor.js file is about 124k. After running 'ng build --prod' my vendor fie size is 2.9mb, with the main.js file being 559kb.

1. What are the things that can increase the size of these two files?
2. Does the amount of imports in each component effect this?
3. What's the best way to reduce these in size?
4. How important is file size? Is 2.9mb a bit ludicrous for this?

**Versions**

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 6.11.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Any assistance on best practice, or how to manage these files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What versions are you on?

Comment: Refer [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack) and try to exclude extra imports.

Comment: Hi Robin - I've just updated my post with the versions :)

Comment: cloud you run `ng -v` in you project folder?

Comment: @Robin - Just did. Updated post with versions listed from that.

Comment: On a side note, make sure to enable script compression on your webserver, that'll help too for low speed connections

Comment: Thanks David, is there a way to do that with Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is with the od version of Material and CDK. I remembered I had the same issue. The best way to reduce the size is to simply update it. Also an update of angular will help. As of Angular5 there is a huge improvement in bundle size.

About that size. 3.5m for an application is a little big. I think it runs fine a desktop with a solid internet connection. However, it might be really annoying on a mobile device. I probably wouldn't accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! - Thankfully there's device apps for what I'm building, but I completely agree, it probably wouldn't be acceptable should a user view it on a mobile. Thank you for the precise points (Material, CDK). Lastly, what's the best way to update these individually, or is there one command that will update them all?

Comment: I would probably start with Angular itself because there are no breaking changes in Angular itself. (simple change the version numbers and run nom install) However, i'm not sure if your version of material works with angular5. Next update material and cdk. You'll get a let of errors. Read the changelog. There is some tool mentioned there that will fix some of them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go :) - It's the only reason I've avoided updating, because errors and npm incompatibilities ruin my day a bit :P